# Could a HM-10 be powered by a LiPo with LDO?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

The [HM-10](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/c/cd/Bluetooth4_en.pdf) BLE module has a VDD range of 2V-3.7V. A fully charged 18650 could be 4.2V (even 4.4V?). Could a HM-10 be powered straight off a 18650? Are modules typically designed to run directly off a LiPo without a LDO?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you risk damaging the module if you run it from a fully powered LiPo cell. An LDO or other form of regulator is your only option when powering most things directly from  a higher-than-rated voltage source.

Perhaps if the voltage of the cell lowered enough you could power it directly, but it would keep drawing current from the cell all the way to 2V, which is far below the voltage you should discharge a LiPo to (I've seen various figures for maximum discharge, but they're all around 3 - 3.4v)

Comment: Oh, my lipo has a protection circuit, so there should be no over-discharge issue. Could a MCP1702 be used as the LDO without any resistor in between?

Comment: Yeah, should function just fine, the module won't draw any more current from the LDO than it needs. Be sure to take into consideration the 'typical application' circuit in the datasheet. Seems like it recommends a 1uF capacitor on the input and output.

Comment: Use of in-cell protection cct for low v cutoff is unwise. This will run cell as abs max min if load allows and does not help cell life. Formal cutoff around 3V is wiser

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer. The lipo itself doesn't have a protection circuit built-in, but that my HM-10 board has a protection circuit built-in (lock out at 2.7V). Is that okay?